# Is Chapman-Kolmogorov equation equivalent to law of total probability?

Tags: probability-theory, markov-process

For a hidden Markov process $\{x_k\}_{k\in {\mathbb N}_0}$ with observations $\{y_k\}_{k\in {\mathbb N}_0}$, the Chapman-Kolmogorov equation is

$$p(x_k|y_0,\ldots,y_{k-1}) = \int_{{\mathcal X}_{k-1}} p(x_k|x_{k-1}) p(x_{k-1}|y_0,\ldots,y_{k-1}) {\mathrm d}x_{k-1}.$$

This form is very similar to the law of total probability. I think they are equivalent, am I right? Thanks!

Comment: It is law of total probability combined with Markov property. Markov properrty is essential for Chapman  -  Komogorov';s equation to hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh, I see. Without the Markovness, one cannot derive $p(x_k|x_{k-1}) = p(x_k|x_{k-1},y_0\ldots,y_{k-1})$. Thanks very much for your helpful comments :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is answered by a helpful comment.